# Realtime DB in Firebase console not loading data

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-console

My console for Firebase realtime database doesn't load data. The *JSON EDITOR* cannot show data.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have the same problem.  There is an ongoing incident (since yesterday) with the Database Console and Firebase/Google are trying to fix it.  The good news is that it seems to only affect the console display....the database is working OK - although it too has had a couple of short glitches in the last 48 hours...

> > Mar 01, 2017    14:06
> >     We have determined the root cause and are working on a fix. We will post an update within 24 hours.
> >         Mar 01, 2017    09:16
> >     We are still investigating the issue where some developers may not be seeing their data load in the Realtime Database Console. We will provide more information by 4:00 PM US/Pacific.

Details here:  [Firebase Status Dashboard](https://status.firebase.google.com/incident/Console/17008)

Comment: Looks like the problem is back again today. The data is served but nothing can be seen in the console. The status says green light. Not good.

Comment: This problem is back again and again. I am trying to access the console from the day on different browsers but still no change. IST 2021-08-25 15:18. Also no information from google about this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Firebase dashboard supports real time view for small amount of data when your db root path contains a lot of child, it will not view changes. Click +(expand) then click child +(expand) buttons, hope you will get data and real time changes.

Comment: this root path not load,